# How to stop streaming from a specific broadcasting in ActionCable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I'm trying to use ActionCable as a transport for GraphQL queries ([`graphql-streaming`](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-streaming/tree/1d4653f47db401cc82051c4a211f98ef47747515)). GraphQL queries are arbitrary requests for data, so rather than having one cable per query, I'd like to have one cable and multiplex queries over that cable. The flow might be like this:

- Connect to ActionCable
- Subscribe to a GraphQL query
- Push a query result
- Something changes in the app, push another query result
- User changes pages, we should unsubscribe from that query

I'm implementing subscription events as streams, so a subscription looks like this:

```
stream_from(event_name) { evaluate_graphql_and_push }
```

But when the user changes pages, I want to keep the channel connected but stop streaming from that event.

Is this possible with ActionCable?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `unsubscribe` method on the subscription (a.k.a. channel) object.

i.e.,

```
channel = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ChannelName"

onPageChange = function() {
    channel.unsubscribe()
}
```

Comment: I don't _think_ that's what I want: I want to stay connected to a channel, but stop receiving events from certain triggers over that channel. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @rmosolgo In that case, you need to implement two methods that streams events and stops streams in Server and invoke those methods using `perform` call in Client.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/actioncable-examples is a good example for what you want.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/actioncable-examples/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/channels/comments.coffee

Comment: https://github.com/rails/actioncable-examples/blob/master/app/channels/comments_channel.rb

Comment: I think that example uses `stop_all_streams`, but I don't want to stop _all_ streams -- I just want to stop _one_ stream!

Comment: @rmosolgo did you ever find a solution without manually calling         pubsub.unsubscribe 'stream_name'

Comment: No! I also asked here and didn't get an answer: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubyonrails-core/58YfToQfBaI/ZGGfyl9ABAAJ

Comment: Too late but this should be easy just copy stop all streams source and implement stop stream method. For me it seems that it works fine, I will provide example